# Jquery array of input IDs detect change

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input, detect

I have a question about detecting changes if inputs in array of input IDs.

For example I have an array of input IDs: `var arrayOfInputs = ['#firstname', '#lastname', '#email', '#phone'];`

My problem is that I want to detect any input change in these fields, BUT I don't want to write a bulky script code for each input field separately.

**So question is: do there is a way to detect input change for all these inputs in array with one or two lines of code with jQuery?**

Maybe I should use something other than array of IDs?

Comment: _I don't want to write a bulky script code for each input field separately_. Have you heard about [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) loop?

Comment: But do it detect input change for one of these fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So question is: do there is a way to detect input change for all these inputs in array with one or two lines of code with jQuery?

Yes:

```
$(arrayOfInputs.join(",")).on("change", function() {
    // Here, `this` will refer to the input that changed
});
```

**Live Demo**:

```js
var arrayOfInputs = ['#firstname', '#lastname', '#email', '#phone'];
$(arrayOfInputs.join(",")).on("change", function() {
  snippet.log(this.id + " changed");
});
```

```html
<div><input type="text" id="firstname"></div>
<div><input type="text" id="lastname"></div>
<div><input type="text" id="email"></div>
<div><input type="text" id="phone"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

> Maybe I should use something other than array of IDs?

Yes, give them all a common class or `data-*` attribute or something instead of listing IDs.

**Live Demo**:

```js
$(".watch-me").on("change", function() {
  snippet.log(this.id + " changed");
});
```

```html
<div><input type="text" class="watch-me" id="firstname"></div>
<div><input type="text" class="watch-me" id="lastname"></div>
<div><input type="text" class="watch-me" id="email"></div>
<div><input type="text" class="watch-me" id="phone"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: IMHO - this will only work if the input loses focus. not at typing stage. ( like ng does). But I like the idea of splitting

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Right, that's how `change` works. For more proactive notification, there's `input`, `keydown`, `keypress`, `paste`, ...

Comment: Related , would you use here keydown/keyup or keypress ?  ( i know that keypress is for visual chars....) but still , what would be your approach here ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It would depend entirely on what I wanted to do in response.

Comment: A true _sigh_  indeed

Comment: I really meant that. Your code is much shorter / dynamic. And yet , the more verbose code has been accepted....

Answer (score 1):

You can use **each()** to do that things in sort code.

```
var arrayOfInputs = ['#firstname', '#lastname', '#email', '#phone'];
$.each(arrayOfInputs, function(index, data){
  $(data).on('change',function(){
     alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: No, you don't need `each` here.

Comment: if you want different type of check for different input then you need to use each i think

Comment: No, if you want a *different* check for each input, you don't want `each`, you want to hook up separate handlers.

Comment: ty, this works perfectly. Plus I changed 'change' to 'input' and this will work event better for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Mac444s: You do understand that the loop in the above is pointless?